# best way to repeat php script after fixed interval

Tags: php

i want my php script to be executed after every 10 seconds until stop button is pressed
Is using an  while loop with sleep() the best way or there is a better way of doing it?

And i want to know that if i run that while loop, will it prevent the other scripts on the page from running?
i mean that during the sleep time, as the PHP script is still running, will browser wait for this script to end of will run other scripts simultaneously?

As far as i have understood, cron wont be helpful in this case as i have to run the script between the time when start and stop button are pressed. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: what about doing it via cron ??

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense because you are implying that PHP is running in the web browser. It runs on the server, not the browser. What you want is javascript to call the function over and over through AJAX or have the page auto-reload every 10 seconds.

Comment: oh you are right! thanks alot!!
i am a newbie and using php first time so i get confused about its implementation. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 5):

Cron would do the job although, with an interval as small as 10 seconds, you'd probably be better off writing a daemon instead (and running from the command line or init.d, not through a web server).

You just need a way to switch it on and off. That could be something as simple as testing to see if a file exists (and then adding or deleting it as desired).

> And i want to know that if i run that while loop, will it prevent the other scripts on the page from running?

You need to make the script stand-alone for this to make any sense at all.

Comment: Aman, I'd add to this that things that are "required" to run every 10 seconds probably don't need to. If data is several minutes out of date, on most websites this doesn't matter. This _might_ matter on financial websites, but probably not for message updates on social networks, for example.